# Save email as 'sent' using ItemSend action in Outlook 2013

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have created a userform in Outlook 2013, which opens based on the Application_ItemSend action.
The userform simply asks for a network drive location to save a copy of the email being sent, checks that the location exists, and then saves a copy of the email (as a .msg) to that location, with some specifics in the file name (date, time, etc).  The code on the OK Button is below (where txtProjNum is a text box on the user form).

```
Private Sub butOK_Click()
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim sPath As String
Dim dtDate As Date
Dim sName As String

' Set File Path
If Left(txtProjNum, 1) = "S" Then
sPath = "N:\Submissions\20" & Mid(txtProjNum, 2, 2) & "\" & txtProjNum & "\Email\Out\"
Else
sPath = "N:\Projects\20" & Left(txtProjNum, 2) & "\" & txtProjNum & "\Email\Out\"
End If

'Check sPath exists
If Dir(sPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
MsgBox ("Folder doesn't exist, try again!")
txtProjNum.SetFocus
txtProjNum.SelStart = 0
txtProjNum.SelLength = Len(txtProjNum)
Exit Sub
End If

' Set File Name
Set oMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
sName = oMail.Subject
ReplaceChars sName, "_"
dtDate = Now()
sName = Format(dtDate, "yy-mm-dd_hhnnss") & " " & sName & ".msg"

' Save Email
Debug.Print sPath & sName
oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG

Unload Me

End Sub
```

This all works fine, except the email that is saved is obviously a version of the email before it is actually sent.  So, if you open the .msg file, it appears as an unsent draft.
What I am hoping to save is a copy of the sent email, so would include the date and time sent, etc.

I understand that I might be able to activate the same code through the Items.ItemsAdd action, though I can't seem to get this to work, and for some larger emails, this is likely to activate some time after the actual email is sent, which is not ideal.

Hopefully, there is a way that I can either save the 'draft' email as a 'sent' email, or somehow wait until the email is sent before saving it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with your Items.ItemAdd event handler? You can "fix" the unsent message created in the ItemSend event handler using Extended MAPI or Redemption, but most importantly, the MSG file created in the ItemSend event handler will be missing all sender related properties.

Comment: The Items.ItemAdd event triggers the Userform, but then the code above doesn't work . . . I get a Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.  A debug identifies the line:Set oMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
I assume this is because the sent item is not the current item.  Even if this did work, as the Items.ItemAdd may not trigger until sometime after the email is sent (particularly for large attachments), it doesn't really suit what I want (and that is to trigger as soon as you press the send button).

Comment: ItemAdd event passes the message as the parameter; you need to use that instead of ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.